# Ionic 3 Firebase Tengo el Key -- Como accedo a los datos?

Tags: firebase, typescript, ionic3

Primeramente, debo aclarar que soy nuevo en la programacion, decidi aventurarme con ionic para comenzar a desarrollar. Mi duda es cuando quiero tomar informacion de firebase siguiendo una ruta teniendo la key respectiva:

Esta es mi tabla usuarios:
[image: tabla usuarios]
Asi es mi html:
[image: llamado en html]
Efectivamente, puedo obtener la key al seleccionar un usuario:
[image: obtencion de key]

esa key la obtuve con un console.log.

Mi pregunta es, teniendo esa key de la ruta, como puedo obtener los valores dentro de ella? Por ejemplo, si de esa key quiero obtener la edad, el objetivo, sexo, etc?

Como quedaria el .ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer es lo siguiente

Para traer todos debajo de `usuario-list`

```
firebase.database().ref().child("usuario-list").on('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var datas = child.val();
var edad=child.val().edad;
var objetivo=child.val().objetivo;
var nombre=child.val().nombre;
  });
});
```

Para pedir de un solo `userID`

```
firebase.database().ref().child("usuario-list").child(userid).on("value", function(snapshot) {

        var edad=snapshot.val().edad;
        var objetivo=snapshot.val().objetivo;
        var nombre=snapshot.val().nombre;
});
```

si antes de `usuario-list` tienes otro padre vas a tener que agregar un child mas antes de `.child("usuario-list")` para poder acceder a este nodo

Comment: Con este codigo: 

![codigo] http://prntscr.com/kgu6qy

Me devuelve muchos undefined

http://prntscr.com/kgu6ys

Comment: si le sacas el .child(this.userid) y le dejas hasta .child("usuario-list") ?

Comment: Necesito solo los datos dentro de la ruta que le mando, si se lo saco en ningun momento especificaria la ruta. De cualquier manera lo intentare a ver. mil gracias , espero continues aca!

Comment: podes dejarle el .child(userid) y sacarle el foreach, ahi deberia funcionar para el userid

Comment: sin el child(userid) meda todos los resultados dentro de la bd, necesito 1 solo, le sacare el foreach http://prntscr.com/kgub50 ... que pongo en vez del foreach para que solo agarre 1 valor en vez de todos?

Comment: si, sacandole el foreach y dejando el .child(userid) deberia funcionar , lo bueno de dejar el foreach es que si lo necesitas para traer todos los datos de los usuarios lo podes hacer de esa forma :)

Comment: que uso en vez del foreach?

Comment: ahi te lo modifico :)

Comment: fijate ahora si funciona

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kgued5 Ya funciona. Ahora, ya se que me ayudaste bastante, pero.. como les asigno esas variables a un objeto que ya tengo creado anteriormente? aqui dejo una imagen del error que recibo al intentarlo: http://prntscr.com/kgufw2   http://prntscr.com/kgug1m    http://prntscr.com/kgug5h